# Arrested for trespassing in church open to public

Tags: washington, trespass, civil-rights

A friend in WA State was recently arrested and indicted for criminal trespassing at a church. Video evidence is clear: no disruption. No outstanding warrants nor trespass. A member of the church said he had to leave. He gave them a sheet with https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9.91.010 printed on it (Denial of Civil Rights).

Police called and arrived. Immediately asked the church security team if they wanted him removed. Member of church team said, "Yes." Man began to present the officers with the sheet with RCW 9.91.010. Officers asked him to leave. He continued to present them the paper. Less than 10 seconds later he was handcuffed and arrested, as the man was repeatedly heard stating, "I was getting ready to leave."

Prosecutor says that the police officers witnessed a crime for probable cause. All on security cam footage (seen it in full). The crime, it seems, is that he wouldn't leave when they told him to. Church was open to the public.

Unfortunately, the county and church is being vindictive. Man also had a body cam which recorded the whole thing. Church surveillance cam has everything too, except the audio is poor. City won't give the body cam back, nor do they seem very interested in getting the evidence off the cam.

Friend is going at this pro se, because county defense lawyers have shown themselves to be corrupt to him in the past.

It's a long story as to why he went back to the church. He meant to discuss a previous issue with the elders. He is a sincere man of faith, very bright, yet extremely talkative, so people don't listen and get frustrated by him.

Question: Is it really probable cause for a trespassing crime if an officer asks you to leave at a church open to the public and don't within 10 seconds. Seems like something out of the Stasi. This is what the Civil Rights Act of 1964 was all about. Any advice?

Edits:
He was not initially asked to leave. In fact, the security team said he could stay if there was no warrant. Another member of the team asked the cops to trespass the person.

He was asked, fumbled with papers, trying to provide them to the cops for about 10 seconds. Then he was handcuffed.

Creed. He was going to follow through with Matthew 18 and seek dialogue with the elders as required by Matthew 18.

WA law considers Real Property a place where the owner can remove you. But a church is not Real property. Cops came in. 98 second later he was in hand cuffs. The long story is that he was accused of trespass and assault 3 years ago. Went to trial and case was dismissed with prejudice. He was returning to talk to the elders because no one would speak to him.

Comment: What happened on the last occasion when he was at the church? What is "a previous issue"?

Comment: where do you base your belief on that churches are public spaces and not owned by a private organisation such as a congregation, and thus the congregation can exclude whoever they want?

Comment: @Trish Its a common confusion I see people have. They conflate public access with public owned. Most churches are open to the public, or have public access.

Answer (score 5):

This site **cannot** give legal advice in specific cases. It can discuss principles of law, or compare how they are implemented in different jurisdictions.

Not having watched and timed either video, the following **sequence** of events seems obvious:

1. The (supposed) trespasser arrives in the church, expecting some conflict -- hence the bodycam and the printouts.
2. A member of the congregation asks the trespasser to leave.
3. A member of the congregation calls the police.
4. The police arrives and talks to some member(s) of the congregation.
5. The police asks the trespasser to leave.
6. The police handcuffs the trespasser.
7. The trespasser claims that he was getting ready to leave.

So the first question would be if the supposed trespass started when the trespasser was asked to leave by a member of the congregation, or only when the police asked the trespasser to leave. In most jurisdictions, a request to leave on the basis of trespass laws must come from a representative of the owner of the property. The police would use a different legal basis.

The second question would be how long the trespasser has to comply to a verbal order before the police can start to use force. You mentioned that the person continued to hand out papers. That is different from e.g. slowly walking away.

The third question would be if the civil rights act overrides the trespass accusation. Here it *might* matter if being "talkative" (as you put it) is a protected category like ethnicity, sexual orientation, or religious beliefs. In most countries, simply having different religious beliefs from the property owner does not protect against trespass charges.

Comment: RCW 9.91.010 allows for the "full enjoyment" of any place of public resort...assemblage...causing a particular...creed...to be treated. WA law considers Real Property a place where the owner can remove you. But a church is not Real property.  Cops came in 98 second later he was in hand cuffs. The long story is that he was accused of trespass and assault 3 years ago. Went to trial and case was dismissed with prejudice. He was returning to talk to the elders because no one would speak to him.

Comment: RCW 9.91.010 (d) "Any place of public resort, accommodation, assemblage...where the public gathers, congregates, or assembles for...public purposes...
(2) Every person who denies to any other person because of...creed...full enjoyment ...shall be guilty of a misdemeanor.

Comment: RCW 9A.52.105
Removal of unauthorized persons...
(1) Subject to subsections (2) and (3) of this section and upon the receipt of a declaration signed under penalty of perjury, in the form prescribed in RCW 9A.52.115, ...Only a peace officer having probable cause to believe that a person is guilty of criminal trespass under RCW 9A.52.070 for knowingly entering or remaining unlawfully in a building considered residential real property...the peace officer must provide the occupant or occupants with a reasonable opportunity to secure and present any credible evidence provided...

Comment: RCW 9A.52.090
Criminal trespass—Defenses.
In any prosecution under RCW 9A.52.070 and 9A.52.080, it is a defense that:
...(2) The premises were at the time open to members of the public and the actor complied with all lawful conditions imposed on access to or remaining in the premises;

Comment: @Davez, you don't have to convince *me* that it was legal, I am not and I cannot be on a jury deciding this. Check my last paragraph, I seriously doubt that he was formally removed because of his **creed**. He was removed for being overly **talkative**, as you did put it. Lawyers use language in a specific, professional context, and non-lawyers trying to argue interpretations without professional training often come to grief.

Comment: 1: He was not initially asked to leave. In fact, the security team said he could stay if there was no warrant. Another member of the team asked the cops to trespass the person. 

2: He was asked, fumbled with papers, trying to provide them to the cops for about 10 seconds. Then he was handcuffed.

3: Creed. He was going to follow through with Matthew 18 and seek dialogue with the elders as required by Matthew 18.

Comment: In this case, he was not overly talkative. Hardly said a thing this time. In my opinion, it is vindictive behavior, because of the previous incident. And the church just happens to host one of the judges and a retired judge. They don't want to look bad in the community. Essentially, they beat him up last time. And he was charged with assault because he tried to defend himself. Again, he was recently fully exonerated.

Comment: @Davez, you should edit your question to include that there was initially permission to stay. But creed in the sense of the civil rights legislation has a very specific meaning, and that is not just having an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer and am not familiar with the jurisdiction, so my answer is a layman's interpretation of your story.

He was trespassed the moment a representative of the property asked him to leave. The crime of trespass was the moment your friend declined to follow this request, before the police arrived. The police established probable cause when they spoke with the security team.

The officer didn't need to speak with your friend. They were within their rights to walk up and arrest him immediately. They choose instead to offer this person a courtesy by asking him to leave. The difference in this moment is that when the police asked him to leave, it was a lawful order.

After the officers gave your friend a lawful order to leave, your friend declined to follow this and his first action was a form of protest/resistance. This is would not be reasonably considered "getting ready to leave" by an onlooker. A side note, this initial refusal to comply with a lawful order may be a separate crime itself.

The form he has, Denial of civil rights, doesn't apply here. That form does not grant immunity or protection from other laws. It certainly does not prevent a private property from trespassing individuals from their property.

An example of what that law applies to would be if a random person unaffiliated with the church entered the church property and began to deny your friend access to the church property or services without the permission/knowledge of the church. This random person would be guilty of denial of civil rights, not the church.

As for advice, you literally need to ask a lawyer for advice. Not websites.
I would like to note, 100% of the court cases I've seen involving pro se has always had a judge strongly discouraging it.

Comment: I wish he wouldn't go pro se. But in the previous situation, his court-appointed representative, did not represent him, but tried to get the court to consider him insane. He's not insane, just very bright. I believe the church is covering for their previous mistakes they made. Total collusion in our small county. And of course, he should have never gone back to the church. He figured someone would talk to him.

Comment: @Davez Without knowing the details of the previous situation I can tell you what makes sense to me. Lawyers typically shy away from pushing insanity pleas. Your friend has some misguided beliefs. He has very strong convictions about general points that may be correct, but some of the nuance may be incorrect. I cant speak on your accusations of the county officials, but if true, don't be open about it. Collect evidence and submit it to state or federal agencies for investigation. Your friend needs to learn how to follow the rules while asserting himself. Its rarely advisable to argue with cops.